# How do I counter enemy Hazards?

Tags: pokemon-x-y, pokemon-sixth-generation

On Pokemon X and Y, I do a lot of online battling. One thing I notice, is that many people use hazards like Toxic Spikes, Stealth Rock, ect. ect.. I know Flying types and Levitate can go around the ground based ones, but not Stealth Rock. Is there a way I can deal with these hazards, or do I just have to tough it out?

Comment: Also note Flying types and Levitate Pokes can be hit by Spikes if Gravity has been used (Although this does mean that Poison-Levitate Gengar will clear away Toxic Spikes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the moves [Rapid Spin](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Rapid_Spin_%28move%29) or [Defog](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Defog_%28move%29) to clear away entry hazards.

To quote Smogon:

> #### Rapid Spin
>
> Deals damage. Removes all layers of entry hazards (ie. Stealth Rock, Spikes, and Toxic Spikes) from the user's side of the field, and also removes the trapping effect of moves such as Fire Spin and Wrap. It also removes Leech Seed from the user.

Check out the full [Smogon's analysis](http://www.smogon.com/bw/moves/rapid_spin) of Rapid Spin, including a list of Pokemon that can learn it.

Four of the best Pokemon that can use Rapid Spin are:

- Donphan
- Forretress
- Starmie
- Tentacruel

**Notes:**

- It is possible to counter Rapid Spin: As it's a normal move, sending out a Ghost Pokemon will cause it to fail, leaving the entry hazards intact as well.
- Defog will remove **all** entry hazards, which includes any of your own.

Answer (score 8):

I actually think that you have a few options, which I will list below:

### Remove them

You can use Rapid Spin and Defog to *remove* entry hazards like [Spikes](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Spikes_(move)), [Toxic Spikes](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Toxic_Spikes_(move)), [Stealth Rock](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Stealth_Rock_(move)) and [Sticky Web](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Trick_Room_(move)).

One issue with those is that you might be losing 1 precious turn with either a low power move, or a no damage move. Of course, this is all part of the battle; to decide whether to set up or to deal damage, and what's more is that spinners can often be predicted and countered with Ghost types, especially since there are a few very good at [Rapid Spin](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Rapid_Spin_%28move%29)-ning.

Some Rapid Spin-ners you might consider:

- Blastoise (level up)
- Tentacruel (egg move)
- Starmie (level up)
- Kabutops (egg move)
- Forretress (level up)
- Donphan (level up)
- Excadrill (level up)
- Avalugg (level up)

Some Defog-ers you might consider:

- Pidgeot (egg move)
- Crobat (egg move)
- Swellow (egg move)
- Scizor (egg move)
- Drifblim (egg move)
- Swanna (level up)
- Braviary (level up)
- Mandibuzz (level up)
- Archeops (egg move)

---

### Endure them

While not as common, you can still let the opponent set field hazards and some teams might just shrug those off.

As you already know, Flying-types, Pokemon with [Levitate](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Levitate_(Ability)), Pokemon with [Air Balloon](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Air_Balloon) and [Baton Pass](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Baton_Pass_(move))-ed [Magnet Rise](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Magnet_Rise_(move)) (granted [Gravity](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Gravity_(move)) is not enforced, or they don't hold [Iron Ball](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Iron_Ball) or are not Baton Pass-ed with [Ingrain](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Ingrain_(move))) are immune to Spikes.

Toxic Spikes can be ignored by the same Pokemon mentioned above about Spikes, with the addition that Poison-types, Steel-types and Pokemon with the ability [Immunity](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Immunity_(Ability)) are also immune to them. As a bonus, Poison-types will also absorb the Toxic Spikes, should they make contact with the ground (this means that a Levitating Gengar won't absorb Toxic Spikes). What's more, Pokemon with the ability [Poison Heal](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Poison_Heal_(Ability)), [Toxic Boost](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Toxic_Boost_(Ability)) and [Guts](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Toxic_Boost_(Ability)) will actually benefit from the Poison status.

Stealth Rock is a bit more tricky, and cannot be as easily ignored as Spikes. Pokemon with typing resistant to Rock are the best at resisting Stealth Rock.

Sticky Web is the latest addition and can be avoided by the same Pokemon as those mentioned to shrug off Spikes, plus Pokemon with the ability [Clear Body](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Clear_Body_(Ability)) and [Contrary](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Contrary_(Ability)) (the latter will have its speed doubled on switching). Some other abilities which might benefit from this hazard are Pokemon with the ability [Defiant](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Defiant_(Ability)) and [Competitive Spirit](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Competitive_Spirit_(Ability)) (where you get a boost in offensive power, which can be nice for tanks). Otherwise, Pokemon which are already slow don't be much affected by it, and you can even get an edge if you have [Trick Room](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Trick_Room_(move)) activated.

Otherwise, Pokemon with the ability [Magic Guard](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Magic_Guard_(Ability)) will completely ignore the effects of Spikes, Toxic Spikes and Stealth Rock.

---

### Reflect them

One last, probably my favourite since I believe you get the most momentum there is to reflect those hazards back at your opponent. Like most non-damaging moves, Spikes, Toxic Spikes, Stealth Rock and Sticky Web can be reflected by [Magic Bounce](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Magic_Bounce_(Ability)) and [Magic Coat](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Magic_Coat_(Move)).

Pokemon with Magic Bounce:

- Espeon (hidden ability)
- Xatu (hidden ability)
- Mega Absol

Pokemon which can learn Magic Coat:

- Girafarig (egg move)
- Dunsparce (egg move)
- Kecleon (egg move)
- Grumpig (level up)
- Absol (egg move)
- Musharna (egg move)
- Delphox (egg move)

Not only you will be free from hazards on a good prediction, but your opponent will be the one with the entry hazards. Isn't that just great? :) Not to mention that both Magic Guard and Magic Coat can be used to reflect a bunch of other things as well; status ailment inducing moves, status reducing moves/abilities.

Answer (score 2):

Any Pokemon that can learn Rapid Spin, like Donphan or Forrettress, or Defog can clear entry hazards. Note that Defog will clear *all* hazards on the field, including the ones that you place yourself. Toxic Spikes can be cleared by sending out any Poison-type Pokemon, as they "absorb" the spikes.

Comment: Is defog available on Pokemon X and Y?

Comment: @Shadow - I imagine it will be after the Pokebank is released in a week

Comment: @ShadowZorgon Yes, Defog is learnable by Ducklett and can be bred onto other Pokemon.

Comment: @Yuki - Nice, completely forgot about Ducklett

Answer (score 1):

Love them or hate them, entry hazards define competitive Pokemon. The very existence of Stealth Rock seriously limits the viability of types weak to Rock. Your options against hazards are:

**Remove it** - with Defog or Rapid Spin. Defog will remove your own entry hazards, however (and because they are so good, this is likely to be very detrimental). Notably Rapid Spin can be blocked by ghost types, which many well-built teams will have. Your counter-to-the-counter is to trap the ghost Pokemon with a Pokemon that knows Pursuit.

It's also worth pointing out that Toxic Spikes can be removed simply by switching in a grounded Poison Pokemon.

**Endure it** - which means you plan to have a team that functions even if Stealth Rock (or one layer of Spikes) is in play. This generally means you don't use Pokemon that are weak to Stealth Rock. Sucks but such is life. If you really want to use something that's weak - or even worse, quadruply weak - to Rock, then you must either back that Pokemon up with some kind of hazard removal (Defog/Rapid Spin), or you must give that Pokemon the item [Heavy Duty Boots](https://www.smogon.com/dex/ss/items/heavy-duty-boots/), which makes it immune to hazard damage.

**Stop it from going up in the first place**. There are a few ways to achieve this, some direct and some more subtle:

- Use a move that stops the hazard move. [Taunt](https://www.smogon.com/dex/ss/moves/taunt/) is the most obvious of these. You need to be faster than the hazard-setter, however (or have the ability Prankster). If the hazard-setter is already in play then this isn't a realistic option to stop the hazard move, since you can't switch to the Taunt-user without giving the opponent a free layer of hazards. Therefore this mostly really applies in the lead situation, where you and your opponent both choose a Pokemon to send into play at the start of the match. A fast Taunter can stop hazards from going up in this case.
- Use a [Magic Bounce](https://www.smogon.com/dex/ss/abilities/magic-bounce/) Pokemon. This has the advantage that you can always switch to the Magic Bounce Pokemon when the enemy hazard-setter is in play, and the disadvantage that there are precious few Pokemon that have Magic Bounce. Note Magic Coat does *not* work against anyone who knows what they're doing, because they'll simply not use the hazard move when you have the Magic Coat Pokemon in play.
- Finally, the more subtle method is to play an offensive team such that opponent taking a turn off to put up entry hazards is very dangerous. For example, if you have a Salamence in play and your opponent uses their turn to put up hazards, then you could use your turn to Dragon Dance (which is a stat-up move that raises ATK and SPE). This makes your Salamence more threatening. If opponent keeps putting up hazards and you get to Dragon Dance again, then Salamence could conceivably sweep the entire enemy team. You don't need a stats-up move for this; any Pokemon with powerful attacks & coverage will suffice.
- The disadvantage of the above method is that you can't switch to your offensive Pokemon without giving the opponent at least one layer of hazards. This disadvantage can be mitigated if *all* of your Pokemon are very threatening (this is the so-called "hyper offense" archetype), or if your stats-up Pokemon is not threatened by the enemy hazard-setter. For example, if your opponent is using Azelf as their hazard-setter, then they can't really threaten your Tyranitar. Say your opponent has Azelf in play, and you switch to Tyranitar as they put up Stealth Rock. Because Azelf cannot threaten Tyranitar, opponent must switch, and you get to use your stat-up move. This is not likely to be sufficient to sweep an intact team, but if the opponent's team is weakened, this can lead to a win. Here is an [example](https://www.smogon.com/forums/threads/do-you-fear-azelf-peak-4.3455947/) of a team that exploits enemy hazards in this way (see what the author wrote about Hitmontop in the threat list).